# Rails 4.2+: Mapping PostgreSQL JSONB nested values to form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, forms, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have a `users` table with a `settings` field of type `JSONB` (using PostgreSQL 9.5).

I'm trying to create a form on a settings page to update `user.settings["notifications"][...]` values.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

user = User.create(settings: { notifications: { post_created: true } })

user.settings["notifications"]["post_created"] # => true
```

To map the nested JSONB values to a form, however, I have to do this:

```
# views/form.html.erb
<input type="check" name="user[settings][notifications][post_created]" checked="<%= current_user.settings['notifications']['post_created']" %>

class SettingsController
  def update
    current_user.settings["notifications"]["post_created"] = params["user"]["settings"]["notifications"]["post_created"]

    current_user.save
  end
end
```

Is there anyway to utilize the power of Rails form builders such that I can do:

```
# will not work, undefined attribute settings['notifications']['post_created']...
<%= form_for current_user, url: settings_path, method: "PUT" do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box "settings['notifications']['post_created']" %>
<% end %>
```

I understand that Rails is trying to map an attribute from the `current_user` object, and there isn't really an "attribute" named `settings['notifications']['post_created']`.

But how does one go about mapping nested JSONB values to a form field for CRUD activity?

A workable (but not really feasible) approach is to created virtual attributes for every single nested value I want to work with:

```
class User
  def settings_notifications_post_created
    settings["notifications"]["post_created"]
  end

  def settings_notifications_post_created=(value)
    settings["notifications"]["post_created"] = value
  end
end

# view...
<%= f.check_box :settings_notifications_post_created %>
```

But this loses any benefit of a conventional system since I'm manually typing out every attribute.  May as well write raw HTML fields and all the getter/setter methods myself...Googling and Stack Overflow haven't been very helpful so far, it seems there aren't very many with experience doing this kind of stuff yet...